# How to add some texts into Microsoft Word file in a specify place

Tags: export, office

Such as I have a office word file named `file.docx`.It have some text in it,Such as

[image]

```
I have a dfj.
This is second line.
Ok. I know that already.
```

Then I want to add some string into the place that the arrow pointting by *MMA*.Is it possible?

Comment: Does it really have to be a *.docx file? The format is quite complicated ([essentially a zipped bunch of XML files](http://www.forensicswiki.org/wiki/Word_Document_(DOCX))) that maybe a text file would be less of a headache.

Comment: @J.M. After I save it as `.xml`,then I import  [some XMLObject](http://i.stack.imgur.com/v2DAJ.png).That's confusing..

Comment: Yes, that's why I'm questioning you if it is really needed to deal with \*.docx instead of, say, \*.txt.

Comment: @J.M. Maybe [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/155065/21532) is what you want to tell me.

Comment: As I mentioned, a \*.docx file is essentially a \*.zip file in disguise; so, you might need to do something like `Import["file.docx", "word\\document.xml"]` (unfortunately I do not have Office or a \*.docx file for testing).

Comment: @J.M. Thanks very very much. You comment always is a good lesson for me.But since `$ImportFormats` don't include `.doc`/`.docx`.Maybe I cannot expected *MMA* can do it.And [your code](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Y3YQa.png) will fail also.

Answer (score 1):

As [this comment](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/155064/how-to-add-some-texts-into-microsoft-word-file-in-a-specify-place?noredirect=1#comment413844_155064),I realize I can *Save As* my *.doc* file into *.xml* file.Then process it

```
file = Import["C:\\Users\\zyd199012\\Desktop\\file.xml"]
Export["file2.xml", 
 Replace[file, 
  "This is second line." :> "This is second Some Text line.", 
  Infinity]]
```

Then *Save As* it back into *.docx* file. Of course,if someone know how to use *MMA* convert the *.docx* file into a *.xml* file,the answer is expected still.